# I do not want to change the array inside the method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods

when I put an array inside my method `public int[] insertionSort(final int array[])` 
I do not change the array[]

```
 public int[] insertionSort(final int array[]) {
        int[] array_for_sorting = array;
        final int[]TempArray = array;
        int n = array_for_sorting.length;
       // printNumbers(TempArray);

        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            int key = array_for_sorting[j];
            int i = j-1;
            while ( (i > -1) && ( array_for_sorting [i] > key ) ) {
                array_for_sorting [i+1] = array_for_sorting [i];
                i--;
            }
            array_for_sorting[i+1] = key;
           // printNumbers(array_for_sortying);
        }
        //array = TempArray;
        printNumbers(TempArray);// for printing
        return array_for_sorting;
    }
```

also, why my TempArray  change after the for loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your array references (`array`, `array_for_sorting`, `TempArray`) are referring the same array object. So, when you modified the array content, it will visible from all its reference.

What does final means here, You can't reassign another array to a final array reference. But, its content can be altered

If you need to copy a arrays, use [`Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29)

Comment: You don't need final here; you can't reassign that array reference.

Comment: @duffymo : I didn't get you.

Comment: "You can't reassign another array to a final array reference" - you can't reassign the reference parameter even if you leave the final off.  Java is pass by value.

Comment: @duffymo : I didn't mean that parameter array reference, I do mean that `TempArray` final array reference.

Comment: that is what i did int[]TempArray=Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);

Comment: I was referring to final int array[], the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `TempArray` and `array` are two referances to same location in memory, so you are modifying the `TempArray` when you modify the `array`

So you need to create a new array like, u can use :

```
System.arraycopy(array, 0, TempArray, 0, array.length );
```

Then modify the Array and another array will not change.